# How to model the relationship between these three tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

This is my first database, it is for a nutritional info meal tracker program. I have created a model in mySql work bench but I'm not sure if I have the relationships right. See image below..[image: Food intake model]

My thinking is that each user would have a new table for each day and each day would have multiple meals. I was thinking that for each day the meal number would go back to 1 as it is the primary key. Would this be a problem i.e. have multiple meals with the same number or would I be able to identify them from the day and the meal number and if so how would I do that? I'm not sure if this is even the best way to design this database so any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

From  Mr.Brownstone's comment I've come up with this new design. Is it possible to have the user_name in MEALS automatically filled in from USER?[image: New model]

Comment: As you already track the `user_id` in the `meals` table I see no need for the `day` table. Just add the `date` directly to the `meals` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not design it so that I had to create new tables all of the time. As you already track the `user_id` in the `meals` table, I would just add another column for the `date` to it and remove the `day` table altogether. I would advise to not make the `date_time` attribute as the primary key though because it is highly probable that more that one person will want to eat on the same day...

You also have a redundant attribute `user_user_id` in the `meals` table because it is already included as `user_id`.

The `user_name` field does not belong in the `meals` table because it is an attribute of a `user`. You can however include the `user_name` in the query used to obtain `meals` items like so:

```
SELECT `date_time`
     , u.`user_id`
     , u.`user_name`
     , `calories`
     , `fat`
     , `carbohydrates`
     , `carbs_which_sugar`
     , `fibre`
     , `protein`
  FROM `meals` AS m
  JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`user_id` = m.`user_id`;
```